# Was heißt »bei jemandem ankommen«?

Tags: verb, phrase

I was reading a book on German verbs and there is an example of the verb "ankommen":

> Das kommt bei mir nicht an.

This is translated in the book as:

> I don't appreciate that.

I asked my German teacher in B2 class and she told me that this is wrong and that this verb can't mean this and she is a german teacher. The problem is that this book is the 5th edition, and this example is in the beginning of the book. So I can't imagine that this is really wrong.

Comment: Welche Übersetzung schlug die Lehrerin denn vor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See our trusted [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen#Bedeutung4):

Meaning 4 for *ankommen* says:

> Anklang, Widerhall finden
>   Gebrauch
>   umgangssprachlich
>
> Beispiele
>   dieser Schlager, das Buch, die Werbung kommt bei den Leuten an
>   die Sängerin kam gut, schlecht, nicht [beim Publikum] an

So in your example, "das kommt (nicht) bei mir an" translates to "I (don't) like / appreciate" (literally "is (not) appreciated by me"), just as your book states.

It's not necessarily reflective (see Duden examples), so your title is misleading, it should be "bei jemandem ankommen".

Comment: I have read this before posting here but the idea is appreciate means in german schätzen and it doesn't mean to like. to appreciate and to like have different meaning but maybe it is true in one way or another

Comment: It's more a matter of style than meaning whether you use *mögen* (everyday German) or *schätzen* (super-posh!) *Es kommt an* is a derived meaning: *it reaches (me)*.

Comment: +1 I learned something new from this answer. But one question. What does *bei* mean in the sentence *Das kommt bei mir nicht an*?

Comment: Is it just a preposition that necessarily goes with ankommen whenever it is used with an indirect object like *mir*?

Comment: @ktm In short: Yes. It's more obvious when you translate it with "to arrive *at*". "At" = "bei", roughly.